# Valgrind reports memory leak from shared object

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a C program that plays mp3 files with [libmpg123](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libmpg123-dev) and [libao](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libao-dev). I use Valgrind to detect memory leak and other potential issues with the following command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose --log-file=valgrind-out.txt ./pac.out
```

In `valgrind-out.txt`, I can see a lot of issues such as the ones below:

```
==14751== 
==14751== 897 bytes in 127 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 143 of 192
==14751==    at 0x48407B4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==14751==    by 0x66AD554: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B02E4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B09DA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B413A: snd_config_update_r (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B474C: snd_config_update (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x665465C: ???
==14751==    by 0x6654CD1: ???
==14751==    by 0x48F1853: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libao.so.4.1.1)
==14751==    by 0x10BE15: play_sound (in /root/bin/public-address-client/pac.out)
==14751==    by 0x10C08F: handle_sound_name_queue (in /root/bin/public-address-client/pac.out)
==14751==    by 0x4995FD3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:442)
==14751== 
==14751== 920 bytes in 56 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 144 of 192
==14751==    at 0x48407B4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==14751==    by 0x66AD554: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66AD8DD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B035C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B09DA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B413A: snd_config_update_r (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B474C: snd_config_update (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x665465C: ???
==14751==    by 0x6654CD1: ???
==14751==    by 0x48F1853: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libao.so.4.1.1)
==14751==    by 0x10BE15: play_sound (in /root/bin/public-address-client/pac.out)
==14751==    by 0x10C08F: handle_sound_name_queue (in /root/bin/public-address-client/pac.out)
==14751== 
==14751== 936 bytes in 13 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 145 of 192
==14751==    at 0x48455EF: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1328)
==14751==    by 0x66ACAB1: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66AD974: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B1109: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B0582: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B060C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B09DA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B0CBB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B0D72: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B2AD4: snd_config_hook_load (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B39DA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==    by 0x66B3EF6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==14751==
```

As Valgrind says the possible leak occurs in `libasound.so.2.0.0`, does it mean there is nothing I can do to fix it from my side?

In case you are wondering, the `play_sound()` function shown in the log can be found [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/public-address-client/blob/027606fa045a86b9a51b3f853f6449dc24d0ce6c/src/utils.c#L17-L141).

Comment: You could try with the [valgrind suppression file for `libmpg123`](https://github.com/madebr/mpg123/blob/master-with-github-ci/valgrind.sup) to see if that helps. I couldn't find one for `libao`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the purpose of this file is to suppress these genuine messages? lol

Comment: "does it mean there is nothing I can do" No it does not. If a library creates an object for you, it is your responsibility to free it when you are done. I recommend building debug versions of your third party libraries and analysing each report.

Comment: It is not that uncommon that libraries don't free everything, for example they may alloc something they need to alloc only once and don't free it when the application closes, because it doesn't matter that much after closing.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind, the purpose of a Valgrind suppression file is, yes, to suppress specific diagnostics that are genuinely emitted by Valgrind.  But whether "genuine" means "valid" or "something to be concerned about" is an altogether different question.  Valgrind comes with a bunch of suppression files.  And even if some of the suppressed diagnostics are, in principle, cause for concern, they are typically things that are outside your control as an application programmer.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind For many libraries, you will need their valgrind suppression file or else the result will be littered with leaks that the library implementors left there for the OS to clean up.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit According to the log I post, do you think we can ascertain the cause of the issue? Is it because I fail to free() the resources from my code or is it the fault of the library developer?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 this is the thing I am unaware of before using Valgrind--is memory leakage so common even in some very popular libraries lol?

Comment: @TedLyngmo will try your suppression file later--but its content does look similar to what I see a lot in my Valgrind report...

Comment: @D.J.Elkind That sounds like good news. Hopefully it will silence everything

Comment: It is hard to tell from this report, a debug version of the library *and* its suppress file (if one exists) will tell you more.

Comment: Does your application end cleanly?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind How you define a memory leak? After the process exits, the OS will retake the memory regardless if you freed it or not. This is why some libraries don't free before exit. It isn't very clean but it has no negative impact on the application or OS (the most annoying thing about it are the valgrind reports).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 a memory leak should be well-defined--after the last pointer that points to a block of memory goes out of scope, there is no mean for the program to reclaim the memory. The memory blocks in question are considered leaked.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind What about static pointers that are usable till the program exits? `--show-leak-kinds=all` shows this kinds of leak.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 as long as we have a pointer that allows us to refer to the object/memory blocks, the memory is not considered leaked. I am not sure if valgrind reports this as well.

Answer (score 1):

The mere fact that the `mpg123` library creators also provide a [valgrind](/questions/tagged/valgrind) suppression file means that there most probably *will* be leaks originating from within the library and that those leaks are deemed safe and that they should be ignored (suppressed).

1. Download the official [valgrind](/questions/tagged/valgrind) suppression file from the library creators: https://mpg123.org/trunk/valgrind.sup
2. Re-run [valgrind](/questions/tagged/valgrind) with the `--suppressions=valgrind.sup` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code for these libraries (if available), compile them locally with debugging information turned on (-g), then link with your project. Now Valgrind can tell you where the leak is in those libraries, i.e. you will see the actual stack instead of lots of "??". If the problem is not on your side (for example, you forgot to free memory from the library that you should have), then you can either fix the bug yourself and offer the fix to the authors of the library, or tell them about the problem and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons

1. The library provides a cleanup function but you didn't call it.
2. The library provides a cleanup function, you do call it but it is buggy and leaks.
3. The library developers were lazy and didn't bother to provide a cleanup function.
4. You application ends abnormally and cleanup is not performed.

Other than laziness there are come cases where cleanup is very difficult. For instance, IO buffers and memory for exception handling which could potentially be needed during program exit.